# Keep getting errors after flutter clean and upgrading to latest version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

So I decided to upgrade the flutter to the latest stable version 2, I used flutter clean then after the flutter upgrade, I kept getting this error intl version dependency

```
PS D:\Flutter\flutter-app> flutter run
Because fstore depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.
So, because fstore depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-app...
pub get failed (1; So, because fstore depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.)
```

so after changing the dependency to

```
dependency_overrides:
 intl: 0.17.0
```

I started getting these errors, *before the clean build and upgrade everything was working fine*

```
PS D:\Flutter\codecanyon-8n5MtXRZ-fluxstore-woocommerce-flutter-ecommerce-full-app> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...
lib/widgets/firebase/firebase_cloud_messaging_wapper.dart:32:24: Error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
 - 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-8.0.0-dev.15/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
                       ^^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/firebase/firebase_cloud_messaging_wapper.dart:42:24: Error: The getter 'onIosSettingsRegistered' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
 - 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-8.0.0-dev.15/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onIosSettingsRegistered'.
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:64:14: Error: Not a constant expression.     
        case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:64:14: Error: 'AuthorizationStatus' is imported from both 'package:apple_sign_in/apple_sign_in.dart' and 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/types.dart'.
        case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:86:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthorizationStatus.error:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:86:14: Error: 'AuthorizationStatus' is imported from both 'package:apple_sign_in/apple_sign_in.dart' and 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/types.dart'.
        case AuthorizationStatus.error:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:89:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/models/user_model.dart:89:14: Error: 'AuthorizationStatus' is imported from both 'package:apple_sign_in/apple_sign_in.dart' and 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/types.dart'.
        case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/home/onboard_screen.dart:207:19: Error: No named parameter with the name 'enableSlideIcon'.
                  enableSlideIcon: true,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/liquid_swipe-2.0.1/lib/liquid_swipe.dart:211:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const LiquidSwipe({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-2.0.0/lib/src/extended_image.dart:786:44: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    _invertColors = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.invertColors ??
                                           ^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wave-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:46:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
            throwNullError('custom', 'colors` or `gradients');
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wave-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:60:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
            throwNullError('custom', 'durations');
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wave-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:66:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
            throwNullError('custom', 'heightPercentages');
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stripe_sdk-4.0.2/lib/src/models/card.dart:55:38: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
      return _ccValidator.validateCVV(cvc, cardType: cardType).isValid;
                                     ^
../Flutter_SDK/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stripe_sdk-4.0.2/lib/src/models/card.dart:57:38: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
      return _ccValidator.validateCVV(cvc).isValid;
                                     ^
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\Flutter_SDK\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\Flutter_SDK\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       342.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It appears you tried to upgrade to Flutter Version 2 of an earlier version of Fluxstore WooCommerce theme from codecanyon. They've updated it to Flutter 2.0 too it's better to contact them, or to fix all dependencies one by one. For example: there's one error of `FirebaseMessaging.configure()`, because it has been removed by firebase team. The solution is to use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage()`.

Comment: There's also the `No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'` error in `MediaQuery`. Upgrading to flutter 2.0 needs null safety, use `MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)` instead of your `MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.invertColors ??` in your `extended_image.dart`. so follow any of these methods from this answer here to safely migrate them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66742816/11040422

Answer (score 3):

Run 'flutter pub upgrade' . It'll update your dependencies to play along nicely with each other.

Comment: Still, after upgrading the dependencies I am getting some errors..

Comment: It's a different type of error, correct? That means progress.

Comment: Yes, please see the above-edited error log

Comment: Fix the errors for each dependency, there is no silver bullet that will the errors go away. Dependancies are updated constantly, and some expressions become deprecated or replaced.