# Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'. after updating to FLutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, debugging

I updated my App to the latest version of the Flutter.
E:\anmol\Jan' 2021 -Backup\nemar_user_(for_new_packages)>flutter --version
Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (3 days ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
Engine • revision 3459eb2436
Tools • Dart 2.12.2

Along with that, I upgraded new packages in pubspec.yaml
When I run my app, then it shows the following errors, I tried so many things but nothing Works. Any Kind of Help would be appreciated.

/E:/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/expandable_text-1.3.2/lib/expandable_text.dart:153:56: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
final locale = Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true);
^^^^^^
/E:/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\flutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the version of Flutter you're using (stable channel, Flutter 2.0.3) is null-safety enabled. [These](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/eliminating-nullok-parameters#migration-guide) are the APIs that were subject to change & so you need to use this [migration guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/eliminating-nullok-parameters#migration-guide) to modify your code to use the new form of the APIs with null safety.

**Method 1:**

Check if you're using any of the aforementioned API dependencies & use `.maybeOf(context)` instead of `.of(context, nullOk: true);`

In your posted code,change your `Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true);`  to `Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context);`

**Method 2:**

Find the dependency that caused the problem & update it to null safety, for example, if you're using `flutter_svg: ^0.19.0` you'll encounter the same error, so either update it to `flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3` or in case you can't migrate to null safety yet, use this version `flutter_svg: ^0.19.3`

**Method 3:**

Alternatively, if you can also downgrade your Flutter version which doesn't provide null safety. It should also fix the error but needs the downgrading. To downgrade to v1.22.6 run the following command:

```
flutter downgrade v1.22.6
```

After each/any method, run the following commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Comment: Thanks for this Help. Method 1 works properly in my case.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to ask more questions, upvote answers that help you & post answers & comments as well. Welcome to the platform @AnmolSahu

Comment: @AnmolSahu you accepted it as the right answer on Mar 22 at 0:32 & then unaccepted the answer again 2 days ago on Apr 2 at 13:29.  You wrote in the previous comment the method 1 worked properly in your case, so may I know what went wrong or am I missing something here? Glad to help anytime.

Comment: Actually, I am not much famileir about the stack overflow jargons and don't what I did wrong. But I am thank-full that you helped me at your solution works in my case.

Comment: Can you help me this error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952211/flutter-signed-build-of-android-is-not-opening-but-all-the-debug-builds-are-work