# Flutter Signed Build of Android is not opening but all the debug builds are working fine?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Debug Builds of the app are working fine but the signed build is not opening.
After Installation of the signed build it shows like this.

[image]

And then couldn't move to Splash screen of the App.
I tried all the solution available on the stack overflow but nothing works for this exact situation.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? And how do you sign you app?

Comment: Using Android Studios and In sign In in the App using mobile no+OTP